# Are there umlaut variants for non-blackletter fonts?

Tags: fonts, accents, characters

In the `yfonts` package for blackletter fonts, there is an option `varumlaut` that puts a tiny "e" instead of the two dots on your umlaut ä, ö, ü.

Is there any other font that has these kind of glyphs? (In particular, I am searching for a Garalde typeface).

Comment: This isn't related to any font. The package uses the command `\DeclareTextComposite` to substitute the input of `\"a` to `ae`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 7):

These old style umlauts were most common in Fraktur typefaces, so i don’t think that there are *any* Antiqua fonts with them as stylistic variant.

So i think the best solution for your problem is to define a new generic command `\oldumlaut{base letter}{accent letter}` to make this glyphs yourself. Here’s a quick and dirty implementation:

```
\newcommand{\oldumlaut}[2]{\leavevmode\smash{\tabcolsep0pt\tabular[b]{c}\tiny #2\\[-1.6ex]#1\endtabular}}
```

But this will only work for regular text and lower case letters. Here’s a more advanced solution with `graphicx` and `tipa`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% Fancy implementation:
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tipa}
    % Maybe you should tweak this for your font:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\oldumlaut}[2]{\Upperaccent[.2ex]{\scalebox{0.5}{#2}}{#1}}

\usepackage{fontspec} % loaded after tipa because of different definition of \sups
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} % or your Garalde font

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\content}{%
W\oldumlaut{a}{e}rme ſtatt Wärme,\\
F\oldumlaut{o}{e}hn statt Föhn,\\
Gl\oldumlaut{u}{e}ck ſtatt Glück.}

\content

\textit{\content}

\end{document}
```

If you want to typeset a longer text with the old umlauts, you probably should define shortcuts like `\newcommand{\oae}{\oldumlaut{a}{e}}`. Or you could even try to make `ä` a active character. But this would be a) nasty and b) annother question ;).

Comment: `\usepackage{newunicodechar}\newunicodechar{ü}{\oldumlaut{u}{e}}`

Comment: That’s clearly a better solution than messing with active characters! I didn’t know your package, so thank you for the hint!

Comment: The package *makes* the characters active, but hides the details from the user. You can do even better: define a conditional, for instance `\newif\ifoldumlauts`, and say `\newunicodechar{ü}{\ifoldumlauts\oldumlaut{u}{e}\else ü\fi}`; try `\oldumlautsfalse ü\oldumlautstrue ü`

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! Of cause the magic has to be done someway :). But for the user, this solution looks much clearer – less TeX, more LaTeX like. And the variant with the conditional is even more user friendly! Especially if one would like to write a package out of this.